# How to open a link with a different protocol than http

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to get a google spreadsheet to open my phone numbers in cell F as callto:// links, so that my voip-software can instantly call this number.
Unfortunately writing callto://number into the cells makes the spreadsheet guess that, the link is http:/callto://number.

So I tried to implement a UI, that reads the number from the cell and issue a window.open, but that is not possible.
Then I tried to put this callto://-link into an anchor element, but that doesn't work either. I also tried to use setHTML but, that doesn't work.

Any ideas how I can get this problem solved?

Comment: I don't think it's possible at all :(

Comment: A similar issue has already been reported in Apps Script Issue tracker. You may star it.
http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1107

Comment: I tend to take the JSON from the sheet into Angular for stuff like this. If you're interested, I can create a demo.

Answer (score 0):

I customised an existing workflow to work for this purpose and it works really well. It is using the Mac application [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) (requires the paid-for Powerpack) to use. The workflow consists of a few parts:

1. Highlight/select the number inside Google Sheets (or any other app)
2. Fire the keyboard shortcut assigned to the Alfred workflow.
3. The workflow copies the number into the clipboard.
4. It escapes any extraneous characters to make it a usable phone number.
5. It prepends the text snippet `tel://` to the number. The workflow can easily be adjusted to use `callto://`
6. It executes the "link" that has been built.
7. FaceTime launches automatically to call using your nearby connected iPhone using Mac's handoff feature. If you use call to links, it may open Skype or other VOIP apps assigned to handle the links natively.

If you like the idea, you may [download my workflow](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/419640/Call%20Selected%20Number%20with%20Facetime.alfredworkflow) and give it a go.